# Most efficient (fast) way to create a pivot table in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Given the following example data but with a very large number of rows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
    ts DATE NOT NULL,
    st VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL CHECK (st IN ('open', 'wip', 'closed')) 
);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (SYSDATE-2, 'closed');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (SYSDATE-2, 'closed');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (SYSDATE-2, 'wip');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (SYSDATE-1, 'closed');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (SYSDATE-1, 'wip');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (SYSDATE-1, 'wip');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (SYSDATE, 'wip');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (SYSDATE, 'open');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (SYSDATE, 'open');
COMMIT;
SELECT * FROM  foo ORDER BY ts;
```

what would be the most efficient (fast) way to create the following (a row for each `ts` with columns for each `st` value) pivot table:

```
ts         open   wip    closed
---------- ------ ------ ------
21.08.2022 0      1      2
22.08.2022 0      2      1
23.08.2022 2      1      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two most obvious options are ... well, pivoting:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from foo
  3  pivot (
  4    count(st)
  5    for st in ('open' as open, 'wip' as wip, 'closed' as closed)
  6  )
  7  order by ts;

TS               OPEN        WIP     CLOSED
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
21.08.2022          0          1          2
22.08.2022          0          2          1
23.08.2022          2          1          0

SQL>
```

or conditional aggregation:

```
SQL> select ts,
  2    sum(case when st = 'open'   then 1 else 0 end) as open,
  3    sum(case when st = 'wip'    then 1 else 0 end) as wip,
  4    sum(case when st = 'closed' then 1 else 0 end) as closed
  5  from foo
  6  group by ts
  7  order by ts;

TS               OPEN        WIP     CLOSED
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
21.08.2022          0          1          2
22.08.2022          0          2          1
23.08.2022          2          1          0

SQL>
```

Is one better or worse than another (or something else), I can't tell - you'd have to do some test on real data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   foo
PIVOT (
  COUNT(*)
  FOR st IN ('open' AS open, 'wip' AS wip, 'closed' AS closed)
)
```

or conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT ts,
       COUNT(CASE st WHEN 'open'   THEN 1 END) AS open,
       COUNT(CASE st WHEN 'wip'    THEN 1 END) AS wip,
       COUNT(CASE st WHEN 'closed' THEN 1 END) AS closed
FROM   foo
GROUP BY ts;
```

Which, for your sample data, both output:

> | TS | OPEN | WIP | CLOSED |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022-08-23 10:33:15 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
> | 2022-08-22 10:33:15 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
> | 2022-08-21 10:33:15 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

---

If you want to aggregate by day (and not by second) then you can use `TRUNC`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT TRUNC(ts) AS ts, st FROM foo)
PIVOT (
  COUNT(*)
  FOR st IN ('open' AS open, 'wip' AS wip, 'closed' AS closed)
)
```

or

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(ts) AS ts,
       COUNT(CASE st WHEN 'open'   THEN 1 END) AS open,
       COUNT(CASE st WHEN 'wip'    THEN 1 END) AS wip,
       COUNT(CASE st WHEN 'closed' THEN 1 END) AS closed
FROM   foo
GROUP BY TRUNC(ts);
```

Which both output:

> | TS | OPEN | WIP | CLOSED |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2022-08-21 00:00:00 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
> | 2022-08-22 00:00:00 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
> | 2022-08-23 00:00:00 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bce2822db74776debe76b91ab3b83fb1)*